# moving files to their original locations after conversion

Tags: linux, bash, libreoffice

I have created a Bash script to convert files from .odt to .pdf, but after conversion, the script moves files into the current working directory. As the script is recurring I want each output file to stay in the location where the original is. Here is the script.

```
#!/bin/bash
​
for file in $(find -type f -name '*.odt')
do
    echo $file
    libreoffice --headless --convert-to pdf $file
done
```

​I have tried setting `--outdir` to be path of directories but it moves all files to those directories. I want converted files to stay in same directory as original files.
​

Comment: Please paste your script there first to eliminate the big problems in advance: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generate the `--outdir` value dynamically, and avoid parsing `find`'s output.

```
find . -type f -name '*.odt' -print -exec sh -c '
for fpath do
  soffice --headless --convert-to pdf --outdir "${fpath%/*}" "$fpath"
done' _ {} +
```